# AJAX: error (deprecated!) works while fails doesn't. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript with AJAX calls. They look like this:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        data: "query_parameters",
                        url: "/some_uri",
                        error: function(data) {
                            error_code;
                        },
                        fail: function(data) {
                            error_code;
                        },
                        success: function(answ) {
                            success_code;
                        }
                    });
```

At first, those calls contained only the *fail:* definition, but when I tried to return an error code (401: Unauthorized), that code was not invoked. Once I added *error:*, however, it started working. I'm not a JavaScript expert - more like a rookie, actually - but I've read that *error:* is now deprecated and *fail:* has to be used instead. What can be the reason for this strange behavior? My jquery is 1.10.2.

Comment: why add error when its the same thing?

Comment: The `error:` property isn't deprecated, the `.error()` method is.

Comment: There is no `fail:` property in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing the options in the `settings` argument with the `jqXHR` methods that can be used for similar purposes. The `jqXHR.error()` method is deprecated in favor of `jqXHR.fail()`. If you want to use the `jqXHR` style, you would write:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "query_parameters",
    url: "/some_uri"
}).fail(function(data) {
    // error code
}).done(function (answ) {
    // success code
});
```

There is no `fail:` option. This has always been called `error:`, and still is. It's not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use deferred. The `error` callback is deprecated. Your updated code will look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "query_parameters",
    url: "/some_uri",
})
.done(function(data) {
    // When the request is done.
    // Handle data
})
.fail(function() {
    // Handle the errors
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. Yet, does the order of the "promise callbacks" matter?  I see that you and Barmar add them in a different sequence. It appears that done would be invoked before fail in this example, correct?

Comment: @Robert No, it doesn't matter. But I like it that way. handle the success and then the fail.